# how to using MySQLdb SELECT with for or while loop

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
import _mysql as mysql
db=mysql.connect('localhost','username','password','database')


db.query("""select * from news""")

result = db.store_result()


print result.num_rows()#two records

#how to loop? without cursor

print result.fetch_row()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
while True:
    record = result.fetch_row()
    if not record: break
    print record
```

I second [@Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams)'s [note of caution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633550/how-to-using-mysqldb-select-with-for-or-while-loop/3633624#3633624) against using `_mysql`. Switch to `import MySQLdb`.

Answer (score 6):

You should not be importing `_mysql`. Symbols that start with a single underscore are for private use. Import `MySQLdb` and read [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) for its use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you plan on using the loop, but you could do something like this:

```
while x < result.num_rows():
    #do something for each row
    X += 1
```